# How to make :q, in spacemacs' evil mode, kill the buffer and delete the window, but not kill Emacs?

Tags: spacemacs, evil, window, kill-buffer

How can I make `:q` in spacemacs' evil mode, kill the buffer and delete the window, but not kill Emacs?

Coming from VI, the habit of closing with `:q/:wq` or `ZZ/ZQ` doesn't translate very well into Emacs.

I'm too new to figure out how to reprogram this.

I've come to really like Spacemacs, but need help in modifying this behavior.

Comment: As far as I know, in vim, `:q` quits vim. To delete a buffer and window you should use `:bd` (I might be wrong, but this is how I remember it). Anyway, these things work similar in Spacemacs. However, for me (and I guess for most SPACEmacs users) the preferred way to achieve this is by pressing `SPC b x` (or equivalently `SPC w x`, but I think `SPC b x` is slightly more convenient to type).

Comment: I agree with what you're saying, however as I'm learning to 'live' in Emacs through Spacemacs and evil-mode, I'm trying to do away with the 'muscle memory' I have from vim. As a terminal editor, quitting to go back to the terminal is 'natural' (at least for me), with Emacs, I want to prevent myself from my old habits. So while what I'm asking is not best-practices, it's a way for me to learn more about how everything works/inter-connects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands entered by pressing `:` are, [similar to vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html), called 'evil-ex-commands'. How to remap them is described in [this issue](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil/issues/622#issuecomment-598735923). For your case, you probably want:

```
(global-set-key [remap evil-quit] 'kill-buffer-and-window)
```

You could add this line to your `dotspacemacs/user-config`.

In the issue, it is also described that the evil-ex bindings are defined in the `evil-ex-commands` variable. Another way to find the binding is via `SPC h d x` (then `q`, for this case).